# Why does my JSON Schema appear to not validate a child object correctly?

Tags: json, jsonschema, xapi

Given the JSON and Schema below, actor.mbox, actor.member[0].objectType and actor.member[0].mbox should all fail.  They do not.  There must be something wrong in my schema.  I think I have narrowed it to something dealing with the IdGroup definition but I cannot find the problem.  Any json schema guru see anything obviously wrong?

JSON

```
{
  "actor": {
    "objectType": "Group",
    "name": "Group Identified",
    "mbox": "http://should.fail.com",
    "member": [
      {
        "objectType": "Agent_shouldfail",
        "name": "xAPI mbox",
        "mbox": "mailto:shouldfail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "verb": {
    "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/attended",
    "display": {
      "en-GB": "attended",
      "en-US": "attended"
    }
  },
  "object": {
    "objectType": "Activity",
    "id": "http://www.example.com/meetings/occurances/34534"
  }
}
```

JSON Schema (stripped down)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "xAPIValidator",
  "description": "Validation schema for xAPI tests",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Statement"
    }
  ],
  "statements": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Statement"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Statement": {
      "$id": "#Statement",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "objectType": {
          "type:": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Agent",
            "Activity",
            "Group",
            "SubStatement",
            "StatementRef"
          ]
        },
        "id": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/uuid"
            }
          ]
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/timestamp"
            }
          ]
        },
        "stored": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/timestamp"
            }
          ]
        },
        "version": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/semanticVersion"
            }
          ]
        },
        "actor": {
          "$id": "#actor",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/allOfAgentGroup"
            }
          ]
        },
        "authority": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/allOfAgentGroup"
            }
          ]
        },
        "verb": {
          "$id": "#verb",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
                }
              ]
            },
            "display": {
              "type": "object",
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/lang5646"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "object": {
          "$id": "#object",
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": true,
          "properties": {
            "objectType": {
              "type:": "string",
              "enum": [
                "Activity",
                "Agent",
                "Group",
                "SubStatement",
                "StatementRef"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "actor",
        "verb",
        "object"
      ]
    },
    "attachment": {
      "properties": {
        "usageType": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
            }
          ]
        },
        "display": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/lang5646"
            }
          ]
        },
        "description": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/lang5646"
            }
          ]
        },
        "contentType": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "\\w+/[-+.\\w]+;?(\\w+.*=\\w+;?)*"
        },
        "length": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "sha2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "fileUrl": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "semanticVersion": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ],
      "pattern": "^([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\\\.([0-9]+)(?:-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+)?$"
    },
    "Agent": {
      "$id": "#Agent",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/IFI"
        }
      ]
    },
    "AnonGroup": {
      "$id": "#AnonGroup",
      "maxProperties": 3,
      "properties": {
        "member": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/allOfAgentGroup"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "objectType": [
          "member"
        ]
      },
      "required": [
        "member"
      ],
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "mbox"
        ]
      },
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "mbox_sha1sum"
        ]
      },
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "openid"
        ]
      },
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "account"
        ]
      }
    },
    "IdGroup": {
      "$id": "#IdGroup",
      "properties": {
        "member": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/allOfAgentGroup"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/IFI"
        }
      ]
    },
    "allOfAgentGroup": {
      "properties": {
        "objectType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Agent",
            "Group"
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "objectType": {
                "const": "Agent"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Agent"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "objectType": {
                "const": "Group"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/IdGroup"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/AnonGroup"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "IFI": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "mbox": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/mailto"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "mbox"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "mbox_sha1sum": {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "\\b[0-9a-f]{5,40}\\b"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "mbox_sha1sum"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "account": {
              "properties": {
                "homePage": {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "homePage",
                "name"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "account"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "openid": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "openid"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "mailto": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "(mailto:)(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"
    },
    "timestamp": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(.[0-9]+)?(Z)?$"
    },
    "URI": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]"
    },
    "uuid": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$"
    },
    "lang5646": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^((?:(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)|(art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang))|((?:([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-(?:[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2}))?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})(-(?:[A-Za-z]{4}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3}))*(-(?:[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z](-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+))*(-(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))?)|(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))$": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "lang5646string": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^((?:(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)|(art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang))|((?:([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-(?:[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2}))?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})(-(?:[A-Za-z]{4}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3}))*(-(?:[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z](-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+))*(-(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))?)|(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))$"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, your schema is wrong. I shall explain...

Comment: There's a LOT of schema included here. For others, could you consider removing the parts you don't think are relevant to the issue please?

Comment: JSON objects with duplicate keys has undefined behaviour. `required` takes an array, so put all the required fields in the same array (and the same for all the not > required duplications). Then I may be better able to help you here.

Comment: I have stripped down the schema.  Don't think I pulled out anything important. I'm looking at the key issue you mentioned.

Comment: Regarding the keys, I assume you are talking about the AnonGroup definition?

Comment: Possibly, but I can’t check now. I worked out the issue but I can’t provide it till later. Only on mobile now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if/then/else` doesn't quite work as you're expecting.

In your schema definition `allOfAgentGroup` has a `oneOf` section.
Let's look at that on it's own.

In your sample data that should fail, let's take the "actor" object on it's own also.

Schema:

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "objectType": {
            "const": "Agent"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": false
      }
    },
    false
  ]
}
```

Instance data:

```
{
  "objectType": "Group",
  "name": "Group Identified",
  "mbox": "http://should.fail.com",
  "member": [
    {
      "objectType": "Agent_shouldfail",
      "name": "xAPI mbox",
      "mbox": "mailto:shouldfail"
    }
  ]
}
```

We know you expect the second part item in the `oneOf` array to fail validation.
For debugging and demonstration purposes, let's assume it does fail, and change it to `false` (which is a valid "JSON Schema", always causing validation to fail on that branch).

Now, given the above schema and instance, you would expect the JSON instance data to fail validation, right?
It does not, and in fact validation passes.

Remember, each JSON Schema keyword adds constraints to your validation requirements.
Let's look at what `if` and `then` actually DO.

`if`

> This validation outcome of this keyword's subschema has no direct
>   effect on the overall validation result. Rather, it controls which of
>   the "then" or "else" keywords are evaluated.
>
> Instances that successfully validate against this keyword's subschema
>   MUST also be valid against the subschema value of the "then" keyword,
>   if present.

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.6

OK, so if the schema of `if` successfully validates, the schema from `then` is applied.

The instance data fails the if condition validation, and so... the schema from `then` is not applied, and you end up with what is effectivly an "empty schema", which means no validation constraints for `oneOf/0`. This results in your `oneOf` asserting validation is successfull, because `oneOf/0` passes and `oneOf/1` fails.

To solve this, you need to add `"then": false` to your object which contains `if` and `then`, in the intance where you want that schema item to fail validation if the `if` condition is not met.

Comment: Understanding how applicator keywords work with boolean logic is a common stumbling block to those writing advanced or complex schemas. You're doing great! =]

Comment: I think this gives me ideas for things to try.  I am trying to get one of the three schemas to apply (Agent, AnonGroup, or IdGroup).